# Where to find javax.websocket .jars for use in project

Tags: java, websocket, pushbullet, javax

I've been attempting to use the Java library, [jPushbullet2](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/jpushbullet2/). One of its dependencies is "[javax.websocket](https://java.net/projects/websocket-spec)". I've searched through the site that the websocket API is located and haven't been able to find a jar to download and use. Does such a thing exist?

I also noticed that the author of jPushbullet2 mentioned Tyrus, which is a "reference implementation", presumable in reference to javax.websocket. Is this what I need? I've already added it to my project's build path along with the other dependencies and have tried to run the first push sample:

```
public class FirstPush {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws PushbulletException {

        PushbulletClient client = new PushbulletClient( "o.F8y8swnMc4MESY5rE1aUw8cFLloFH2uH" );
        String result = client.sendNote(null, "My First Push", "Great library. All my devices can see this!");
        System.out.println( "Result: " + result );

    }

}
```

However, this unfortunately results in the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/CloseReason$CloseCode
at practice.FirstPush.main(FirstPush.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.CloseReason$CloseCode
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

This makes sense, since I don't have any jars from javax, only from Tyrus.

I'm very new to the external-library scene, as you probably can tell. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I had to add 2 jar files to my project: `javax.websocket-client-api-1.1.jar` and `tyrus-standalone-client-1.9.jar` to make it work. A simple google search did the job:

https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=javax.websocket-client-api&g=javax.websocket&v=1.1&downloadable=1

and

https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=tyrus-standalone-client&g=org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles&v=1.9&downloadable=1.